# VB.Net connection

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, database-connection

I'm slowly transitioning to VB.Net and it seems like the simplest of things are completely different. I'm trying to do a connection to SQL Server and just grab some data. I've tested the connection and it's fine. Now I'm trying to simply select some data from the server and display the first name in the Msgbox (or anything for that matter). Here is the code I've gotten so far....

```vb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Public conn As New SqlConnection("data source=Tuys1;initial catalog=DDDBuyer; user ID=userID; password=password")
    Private dA As New SqlDataAdapter("Select FirstName, LastName from tblBuyers where Buyerid=1473", conn)
    Private dS As New DataSet
End Class
```

I'm not really sure how to go from here... I understand there is something like

```vb
.hasRows

if ds.hasrows then
   msgbox = "HELLO"
End if
```

or something like displaying the FirstName in txtFirstName

I am trying to get an idea of how ths works and after some research it's hard to find a specific example that would help me do what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Probably you need to read some basic tutorial on ADO.NET (the MSDN contains a lot of examples, just search) However, after creating the adapter you need to [Fill the DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377a8x4t(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and then read the content of the first DataTable DataRow by DataRow. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2   You need to use Fill method

Comment: @steve but i don't need it to fill anything. I want to just display the first name in txtFirstName. Fill is for table? fro what I'm finding out

Comment: Then do not use a DataAdapter but an SqlDataReader. Again start from the basics reading a tutorial otherwise you will only raise your confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Dim custAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter( _
  "SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers", customerConnection)

Dim ordAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter( _
  "SELECT * FROM Orders", orderConnection)

Dim customerOrders As DataSet = New DataSet()
custAdapter.Fill(customerOrders, "Customers")
ordAdapter.Fill(customerOrders, "Orders")

Dim relation As DataRelation = _
  customerOrders.Relations.Add("CustOrders", _
  customerOrders.Tables("Customers").Columns("CustomerID"), _ 
  customerOrders.Tables("Orders").Columns("CustomerID"))

Dim pRow, cRow As DataRow
For Each pRow In customerOrders.Tables("Customers").Rows
  Console.WriteLine(pRow("CustomerID").ToString())

  For Each cRow In pRow.GetChildRows(relation)
    Console.WriteLine(vbTab & cRow("OrderID").ToString())
  Next
Next
```

[As explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)